# How to get the line number of those lines that have a specific character?

Tags: text-processing

I have a population file, looks like this:

```
Pop_ID
good
HA_27
HA_14
HA_1
HA_20
HA_17
HA_26
HA_22
HA_7
HA_7
HA_16
HA_14
HA_2
HA_1
HA_11
HA_3
HA_7
HA_25
HA_23
```

I want to print the line number of those lines that has a specific character. For instance, "`HA_1`" where lines 5 and 15 have this character.

```
5
15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`.

```
awk '/\<HA_1\>/{print NR}' infile
```

With `sed`.

```
sed -n '/\<HA_1\>/=' infile
```

Comment: Thanks so much @afshin, one last question. I have another file and I want to extract only those column which their column number matches to the line number of HA_1 that I produced from your file above! How can I do that! Sorry I am R-expert very beginner in Unix!

Comment: Thanks and you are welcome! Sounds it's easy job, do you have question for that? can you post the link to that? also don't forget to mark one of the answer which helped you and mainly solved your question :  )

Comment: Note that not all `awk` or `sed` implementations support `vi`'s `\<` `\>` operators. Those are not POSIX. Even on Solaris (the system from the company co-founded by the author of `vi`), `\<` is supported in `sed` but not `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/^HA_1$/=' file
5
15
```

The `sed` expression `/^HA_1$/=` will apply the `=` command to all lines matching the regular expression `^HA_1$`.  The `=` command will output the current line number, and the regular expression matches any line whose sole content is `HA_1`.

Answer (score 1):

**grep** + **cut** approach:

```
grep -wn 'HA_1' file | cut -d':' -f1
```

The output:

```
5
15
```